# Can I cheat my way to get a no longer tradeable Pokemon and then transfer it to a newer game?

Tags: cheats, nintendo-ds, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

So basically what I want to do is get event exclusive Pokémon for Platinum (Darkrai, Manaphy/Phione, Shaymin, Regigigas and Arceus) by using my ACE3DS+, and then transfer those to my Pokémon White (I have legitimate copies of both games, but I don't have an Action Replay).

I missed the events where I could get them and only managed to get the shiny Dog 3 + Celebi when events happened for DP/PL/PT.
Since servers are no longer maintained for either Gen 4 or 5 I wondered if I should be able to do it.

Will the "hacked" Pokémon be usable for White once transferred, or is it a lost endeavour and I should just give up entirely?

Comment: I dont have an expertise in pokemon, but coming from a programmation background i would it find really illogical that a pokemon would have a marker showing its gotten by an non-official way, and then only to get you in the knees when you try to transfer it. That would mean the game is made to recognise the pokemon is gotten in not the official way, but not stopping you from getting it. Which makes no sense if they wanted to stop you, knew you had an illegitimate pokemon, and then let you do it anyways (but put a small marker down to screw you later)

Comment: @Fredy31 It's more a case of there are various checks for illegitimate Pokémon (having the right personality values, ball, area met, etc.) which are generally only checked when you try to trade it or battle online with it. If a hacker is careful to make a Pokémon with exactly the same values as a real one, the checks won't pick it up, but shoddily made hacks will fail the checks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a legitimate copy of Platinum, there is a chance you can use the exploit mentioned here: https://www.shacknews.com/article/108512/how-to-unlock-gen-4-and-5-pokemon-mystery-events-in-2018
to obtain the Mystery Events that you missed. You do apparently need a compatible internet router (an Android phone also works), but the basic steps are as follows:

1. First, make sure Mystery Gifts are unlocked in your copy of Platinum - Head to Jubilife City and into the Jubilife TV building. On the third floor, find the man in the bottom left area and he will ask two questions. For the first question, choose “Everyone” “Happy”, then for question two, answer “Wi-fi” “Connection”. This will unlock Mystery Gift in the usual menu before you start the game.
2. From the start menu (before beginning the game) choose Nintendo WFC Settings.
3. If you're using the Android Phone method, set it up as a portable hotspot with security set to none. Otherwise you need a router with WEP protocol. Obviously both methods are a bit of a security risk these days, so don't leave them on for long!
4. Search for an access point within the Pokémon game, and connect to your hotspot (if you're using a 3DS make sure the wifi is switched on on the console before entering the game). Now go back into the settings, and turn off Auto Obtain DNS - instead, type in the Primary DNS as "164.132.044.106" (leave the secondary one as all 0s).
5. Save the settings, then back out of that menu and choose the Mystery Gift option. Search for a gift with Nintendo WFC and receive it. You'll have to go back into Mystery Gift multiple times to receive all the gifts.

I tested it out using my phone as a hotspot and it worked perfectly, giving me the [Rise of Darkrai](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_local_English_event_Pok%C3%A9mon_distributions_in_Generation_IV) mystery gift!

Comment: I've heard that this method can give you the Pokémons in Platinum(and apparently, it works for ~BW2?), but I also heard that they'll disappear when you tried to send them to Sword/Shield. Is that still a thing?

Comment: @Skye-AT If you use the mystery gift to get the Azure Flute/Member Card/Oak's Letter and use them to access the event in your game, those Pokémon should be identical to the ones obtained in the past so there certainly should be problems with that Dakrai and Shaymin (of course the Azure Flute was never actually distributed, so not sure about the Arceus). I don't have subscriptions to Bank and Home, so haven't tried the transfer myself.

Comment: I am suspecting that they'll detect that it's not legit by the day of capture/acquired date(which is, the only thing that isn't identical to truly legit Pokémons.) If I were to doubt, that's the only place I would look for - since normally it should be at, according to your link, somewhere around 2007 to 2011(varies by specific Pokémons.) And I suspect that NDS/3DS wouldn't connect to Wifi if the console's date is set by manually, because of trusted certificate thing. All just speculation though, since I also doesn't have access to the Bank and Home, and most importantly, NDS/3DS.